# Riemannian distance can be approached by geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold, and let $x$ and $y$ be two points of $M$.

The Riemannian distance between $x$ and $y$ is defined as the infimum of lenghts of all piecewise smooth curves connecting $x$ and $y$, so by definition the distance can be approached by taking the lenghts of some sequence of piecewise smooth curves.  But I want to know (and I am not sure if this is true) if the curves of that sequence can be chosen to be geodesics. If I word it differently, does there exist a sequence of piecewise smooth geodesic curves such that their lengths converge to the distance between $x$ and $y$?

Comment: What do you mean by "piecewise smooth geodesic curves"? Geodesic are always smooth.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I meant by that curves that are continuous and that can be divided to "slices", and on each slice or partition the curve is a smooth geodesic. You can call them "broken geodesics". The reason why I allowed geodesics to not be perfectly smooth is because smooth geodesics are only guaranteed to exist in complete manifolds, meanwhile in a connected manifold any two points can be joined by a broken geodesic.

Comment: You should call such curves "piecewise-geodesic" or "broken geodesic". More importantly, what did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Besides vague visual arguments on a piece of paper, I have no idea to approach the problem rigourously. Moreover, as I said in the post, I don't actually know if this is true.

Comment: Did you try the case of open subsets of the plane with the standard (flat) metric tensor?

Comment: @OP the case of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is a good start

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think the answer is clearly yes in vector spaces but I want to generalize beyond intuitive simple cases

Comment: @MoisheKohan when I said I don't know if it's true or not, I  meant it in the case of abstract non complete manifolds

Comment: If course. Try to prove the claim (with a complete argument!) in the special case first. Once you are done, think if the proof works in general.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Proving it in that special case will be completely useless even impossible to generalize because vector spaces have that neat special property called flatness which is very very strong in riemannian geometry

Comment: @randomexchanger I wouldn't be so sure of that. Every Riemannian manifold is locally diffeomorphic to Euclidean space.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade in Riemannian geometry we say that manifolds look the same when they are locally isometric not just diffeomorphic, and only flat manifolds are locally isometric with vector spaces

Comment: @randomexchanger I know. But don't be so sure that proving the special case of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ will be completely useless. Have a go at it first.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade since you all want to know so bad the proof in that case, here it is : if y is not the central inversion of x, you can join them by a segment. If y is the central inversion of x, after a rotation (which is an isometry) suppose x and y are on the real line and y=-x, join x to the point (0,1/n) and join (0,1/n) to y. And when n goes to infinity we approach the distance. Now tell me how we can generalise this proof. In my opinion, you can't. Because in a flat manifold, geodesic are segments so it works easily thanks to flatness, remove flatness and see if it works the same.

Comment: If you do it right in the special case, the same proof will work in general.

Comment: @randomexchanger There is an issue in the proof we wanted so bad that you are proposing: $(-2,0)$ is not the central inversion of $(1,0)$, but these two points can't be joined by a geodesic.
But you can easily fix this. And I assure you that this can be used to generalize for Riemannian manifolds. Here's a hint: locally, there is a unique geodesic segment joining two points.

Comment: @randomexchanger  Hint 2: for a path that realizes the distance between two points up to a constant $\varepsilon$, can you find a piecewise-geodesic  that has length no more than that of the previous one thanks to the first hint, and is joining the same endpoints?
Hint 3: don't hesitate to sketch it on paper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Proof by picture

[image]

### Proof by unnecessary complicated sequence of symbols

Let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct points in the connected Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.
Let $\gamma\colon [0,L]\to M$ be any piecewise-$\mathcal{C}^1$ path joining $x$ and $y$, parametrised by arc length.
Let us prove that there exists a piecewise-geodesic path joining $x$ and $y$ with length less than that of $\gamma$.

For any $p \in \gamma\left([0,L]\right)$, there exists $\varepsilon_p>0$ such that the ball $B(p,\varepsilon_p)$ is a normal neighbourhood of $p$.
By compactness of $\gamma\left([0,L]\right)$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for any $p \in \gamma\left([0,L]\right)$, $B(p,\varepsilon)$ is a normal neighbourhood of $p$.

Choose $N>0$ large enough so that $\frac{L}{N} < \varepsilon$.
Consider the sequence of points $\{x_i\}_{i=0,\ldots, N}$ defined by $x_i = \gamma\left(i\frac{L}{N}\right)$.
For $i\in \{0,\ldots,N-1\}$, we have $d(x_i,x_{i+1}) \leqslant \frac{L}{N}$, since $\gamma$ is parametrised by arc length.
Hence, $x_{i+1}$ belongs to the normal neighbourhood $B(x_i,\varepsilon)$ of $x_i$.
Let $c_i$ be the unique geodesic segment joining $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$.
It has length less than $\frac{L}{N}$.

Define $c$ to be the concatenation of $c_0,\ldots,c_{N-1}$.
Then $c$ is a piecewise-geodesic joining $x$ to $y$, of length less than $L$, which is the length of $\gamma$.

As a corollary, one can find a piecewise-geodesic joining $x$ to $y$ of length less than $d(x,y) + \delta$, for any $\delta > 0$.

Comment: +1, Great answer! Just a minor comment: I think you meant image instead of support when you said "For any $p$ on the support of $\gamma$ (...)"

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Thanks, you must be right. Also we generally use *support* in the usual meaning in French, in the context of a parametrised curve it means its image. Sorry about that!